# Templates befriending each other

Tags: c++, templates, syntax-error

I have a `ResourcePtr<T>` class template and a `ResouceManager<T>` template. I want the two to befriend one another. If I do the following I get a compilation error; how can I fix this?

```
template<class T>
class ResourcePtr
{
    friend class ResourceManager<T>;
};

template<class T>
class ResourceManager
{
    friend class ResourcePtr<T>;
};
```

> error C2059: syntax error : '<'
>   error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As usual for mutual things: declare one before the definition of the other.

```
template<class T>
class ResourceManager;

template<class T>
class ResourcePtr
{
    friend class ResourceManager<T>;
};

template<class T>
class ResourceManager
{
    friend class ResourcePtr<T>;
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Instead of forward declaring it, I did `template<class T> friend class ResourceManager;` directly because it's shorter. :D

Comment: @Paul: it has a different meaning. AProgra's method declares only `ResourceManager<T>` **with the same T** be a friend, your method declares any ResourceManager be a friend.